# Apple's AirPort App

Tags: ipad, ios, applications, airport

Apple just released an app that helps you configure your apple router. I downloaded it to try it out and when I opened my iPad's Apps tab in iTunes I noticed you can transfer documents to this app. I would like to know what kind of documents can you transfer and for what purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backups of your current setup and config, and restores of same.

Comment: in the iPad where does the file show up?